# Basic questions about wx.Dialog

Tags: wxpython

I would like to create a dialog with wx.Dialog.

I have two questions on that.

Do I have to set a wx.Frame as a parent window or can I use my wx.Dialog as the main window?

Are the Sizers usables in a wx.Dialog without parent?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order No, you don't have to set a wx.Frame
Yes, you can use a Dialog on its own
Yes, sizers can be used in the dialog
Here's an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import wx
class TestDialog(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent, msg, title):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, id=-1, title=title)
        Buttons = []
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,1, "Approve Location"))
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,2, "Approve Item"))
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,3, "Change Qty"))
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self,4, "Approve"))
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5,3)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[0], (0, 5), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[1], (1, 4), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[2], (1, 5), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        sizer.Add(Buttons[3], (2, 5), (1,1), wx.EXPAND)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnLocation, id=1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnItem, id=2)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnQty, id=3)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnApprove, id=4)
        self.buttonpressed = None
        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
        self.Centre()
    def OnLocation(self,event):
        self.EndModal(1)
        self.buttonpressed="Location"
    def OnItem(self,event):
        self.EndModal(2)
        self.buttonpressed="Item"
    def OnQty(self,event):
        self.EndModal(3)
        self.buttonpressed="Qty"
    def OnApprove(self,event):
        self.EndModal(4)
        self.buttonpressed="Approve"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    dlg = TestDialog(None, "test my dialog", "Test Title")
    val = dlg.ShowModal()
    print "Dialog numeric result: " + str(val)
    print "Dialog text: " + str(dlg.buttonpressed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Pass `None` as the parent. This should have no impact on sizer behavior. Just be sure to destroy the dialog after it closes to prevent an orphaned dialog.